# How to tell if a function is being called from a multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a C++ function which is being called by a framework whose code I do not have access to. If the framework calls this code from multiple threads, I need to place mutex locks in a number of places. If it doesn't, I do not want the take the performance penalty of the mutexes. Given that I can run the code via the framework, is there a way to determine if the framework is calling the function from a multiple threads?

Comment: Personally, I'd just plop in a little debug code and write all the thread ID's to a file (with the mutex in place of course). Actually, that's not true. I'd put the mutex in and worry when someone told me the code was too slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have c++11, you can use `std::this_thread::get_id()` and store/log this value on every function call. E.g.,

```
void my_func()
{
   std::cout << "my_func called from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
   ...
}
```

Comment: And if C++11 is not available, every OS has a native function to get the thread id.

Comment: This does not work in the general case, the thread_id may be recycle and used by new threads.

Comment: @quantdev Within a single process?  I expect this is a theoretical possibility, and worth noting, so thanks, but not a practical possibility.  I've used the technique above for years for just the sort of debugging OP wants to do and never been misled.  Worst case scenario: run the program again, lightning probably won't strike twice.

Comment: Even if it was recycled, that could only be done after the first thread exited. You'd be talking about sequential threads. For the stated purpose (determine if multiple **concurrent** threads are in use) it's sufficient to print the ID as IDs are unique at any moment.

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient to detect concurrent access to a function, which is what the OP asks about. It will show which threads have called the function, but the access could be sequential rather than concurrent.

Answer (score -2):

Captain Obvlious' comment is very important: RTFM. If you can't find instruction in the doc, you can either use `std::this_thread::get_id()` as Matt point it out, or, if you don't want to edit any code, use a **debugger**!

Simply set up a breakpoint for for the symbol corresponding to the framework function you're interested in and run your program. Decent debugger can even accept regex to create several breakpoints with one command. When the program stop, just look at the thread id and you'll know if you have a critical section or not.

Here are lldb and gdb way of setting breakpoints with a regex:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex regular-expression
(gdb) rbreak regular-expression
```